# @CollectionId using associated sequence plus a default

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have a `@CollectionId` that I want to behave the same that `@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` behaves on identity fields elsewhere in my code. That is, I want a sequence to be created for the `@CollectionID` along with a specified default value.

When I generate an identity field in my code like this:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Integer id;
```

..the resulting schema contains this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE product_id_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;

ALTER TABLE ONLY product ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('product_id_seq'::regclass);
```

Note that a sequence is created for my id field and that a default value using that sequence is specified. This is the behavior that I want applied to my `@CollectionId`.

Here is how I am defining a join table:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "customer_product",
        indexes = {@Index(columnList = "productId")},
        uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"customerId", "productId"}),
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "customerId", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "productId", referencedColumnName = "id"))
@CollectionId(columns = @Column(name = "id"),
        type = @Type(type = "long"),
        generator = "sequence")
private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
```

This doesn't get me a default value on the `customer_product.id` field, nor is a sequence created for the id field.

How can I configure the `@CollectionId` annotation so that a sequence is created and a default value is specified for the id field?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `columnDefinition` property of the `@Column` annotation inside the @CollectionId annotation to specify postgres specific overrides to the column definition:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "customer_product",
    indexes = {@Index(columnList = "productId")},
    uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"customerId", "productId"}),
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "customerId", referencedColumnName = "id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "productId", referencedColumnName = "id"))
@CollectionId(columns = @Column(name = "id",  columnDefinition = "serial NOT NULL"),
    type = @Type(type = "long"),
    generator = "sequence")
private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
```